# How to use Twig loop value in an included SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, twig

I am trying to create an online forum with multiple forum categories. I have made a overview with all the categories, and under the name of each category, I want to link to the latest post in the mentioned category, something like this:

> **MY FORUM**
>
> **Cool category**
>  Latest post: Test thread by John Doe
>
> **Interesting category**
>  Latest post: Another test thread by Jane Doe
>
> **Funny category**
>  Latest post: Jokes thread by John Doe

So, I have made a SQL query to fetch all the forum categories:

```
$forumCategories = DB::run('SELECT * FROM forumCategories ORDER BY id ASC')->fetchAll();
```

And turned it into a global variable:

```
$twig->addGlobal('forumCategories', $forumCategories);
```

And made a for loop to list all the categories:

```
{% for category in forumCategories %}
    <h3>{{category.title}}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

So far, so good.

But now, I want to show the latest posts in each category. I want to run a SQL query and fetch the latest post from the table forumPosts, for each forum category, and show it inside the loop. I need to show a row from forumPosts where category is the same as category.id in the loop. How do I do this?

---

Database structure and content:

```
CREATE TABLE `forumCategories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `urlTitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `forumCategories` (`id`, `title`, `urlTitle`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1,'Hovedrommet','hovedrommet','Dette er hovedrommet på Nye Dofo.'),
    (2,'Forumleker','forumleker','Her kan man leke ulike forumleker.');

CREATE TABLE `forumPosts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `urlTitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `forumPosts` (`id`, `title`, `urlTitle`, `category`, `content`)
VALUES
    (1,'Test','test',1,'Dette er test1.'),
    (2,'Test2','test2',1,'Dette er test2.'),
    (3,'Test3','test3',2,'Dette er test3.'),
    (4,'Test4','test4',2,'Dette er test4.');
```

The output I want is a loop with "title" of all categories, and "title" of the latest post (the one with highest ID) in each category. I manage to get the category name, but not the latest post.

I want the following output:

Hovedrommet
Latest post: Test2

Forumleker
Latest post: Test4

Comment: It would help to see table structure, some sample data, and the output you expect.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have now updated the original question

Comment: Which column can be used to find the latest post?

Comment: I want to find the post with highest "id" in "forumPosts" that also has same "category" value as the "id" column value in "forumCategories".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is a fairly routine query.  Just join the two tables together *and* also join to a subquery which finds the latest post for each category.

```
SELECT
    fc.title,
    fp1.title
FROM forumPosts fp1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT category, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM forumPosts
    GROUP BY category
) fp2
    ON fp1.category = fp2.category AND
       fp1.id = fp2.max_id
INNER JOIN forumCategories fc
    ON fp1.category = fc.id
```

**Output:**

```
        title   title
1   Hovedrommet Test2
2   Forumleker  Test4
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Answer (score 2):

It is generally not best practice to include queries in your template as the goal should be to separate the model and view as much as possible.

I would use the controller to collect the data for the view and organize it in a manner that the view can then digest and pass it directly to the view without using the global.

EDITED FOR FUTURE REFERENCE

For example, you could use the query provided by  Tim Biegeleisen or similar to collect the data:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, p.urlTitle, c.title 
FROM (select * from forumPosts order by category, id DESC) p
JOIN forumCategories c ON c.id = p.category 
GROUP BY p.category
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0d35/28

and store the result into your variable:

```
$forumCategories = DB::run($query)->fetchAll();
```

Then you can pass the whole thing to the template with something like this:

```
$this->render('template.twig', array('forumCategories' => $categories));
```

Then to access it in the template, you could do something like the following:

```
{% for category in forumCategories %}
    <h3>{{category.categoryTitle}}</h3>
    <h4><a href="path/to/article/{{ category.urlTitle }}">{{ category.title }}</a></h4>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! I prefer your solution over the second one since your query is shorter and less complicated - there is only one problem, it shows the oldest post instead of the newest one. It needs to show the one with the highest ID value. Although you have managed to output the correct IDs in the "id" column, the post information is about the posts with the lowest ID values. What would fix this?

Comment: @Tim, yes you are definitely correct, I was a little cavalier with my query and it was incorrect. My main point was that the work should be done in the controller and not in the view. Your answer is definitely the correct one if the OP just needed the correct way of pulling the data.